# Overriding translations from admin-web in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Thera are some tranlations in `com.liferay.plugins.admin.web` or `com.liferay.portal.instances.web` module which I'd like to override. With other modules I've followed succesfully this tutorial:
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-a-modules-language-keys

In this case, `com.liferay.plugins.admin.web` module has no servlet.context.name, which is required in class properties. Is there any way to override this tranlations? Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a translation module which extends from ResourceBundle:

```
package com.galian.extranet.resourcebundle;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.language.UTF8Control;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

/**
 * @author
 *
 */
@Component(immediate = true, property = { "language.id=en_US" }, service = ResourceBundle.class)
public class DefaultCustomResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return _resourceBundle.getKeys();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return _resourceBundle.getObject(key);
    }

    private final ResourceBundle _resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("content.Language", UTF8Control.INSTANCE);

}
```

Your module project structure will be like this:

[image]